# How does it get determined which layout handles a request will use?

Tags: php, layout, configuration, update-handle

Which rules exist?

Is it just a question of configuration?

Can I manipulate it?

Is the order relevant (which I have seen with the [Layoutviewer module](https://github.com/astorm/LayoutViewer))?

Comment: Are you talking about layout handles? If yes please update your question to clarify that.

Comment: Did that. Are there any other handles in Magento? With which could they get confused?

Comment: There is nothing else called "handles" by Magento but you would be wondering how creative people can get with words when they try to describe things. ;-) I was pretty sure you were talking about layout handles butI didn't want to edit the question without asking you.

Answer (score 7):

You should start looking at the method `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::loadLayout`.

If you don't specify a parameter to it the `<default>` handle will be loaded.
Then the action layout will be added.
That is determined based on the module, controller and action.
If your url is `module/controller/action` then the handle `<module_controller_action>` will be loaded.
If the controller contains an underscore it will not affect the mapping.
so `module/some_controller/action` translates to the handle `<module_some_controller_action>`.

Of course there are some requests that have additional handles loaded via controller or helper.

Let's take for example the category view page. Beside the action handle `<catalog_category_view>` magento also load `<catalog_category_default>` or `<catalog_category_layered>` depending if the category is marked as anchor or not. `<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>` is also loaded if the category does not have child categories. To get a clear view take a look at `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController::viewAction` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getLayoutUpdateHandle`.

For products the layout handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_{typehere}` is loaded. Where `{typehere}` is the product type (simple, configurable, ...).  For this see `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View::initProductLayout`.

And one last thing. If a layout handle contains this node as a child `<update handle="other_handle">` then the handle `other_handle` will be loaded.

Comment: Thank you so far. I see now that some handles are added automatically (default, by-update handles) and some programmatically (in the action method). Is this correct? Further question: on the start page (in a newly created shop instance), where does 'cms_page' come from? Why is it additional to cms_index_index handle?

Comment: `cms_index_index` is the handle for the index page. The homepage request maps the the cms module , index controller, index action.  `cms_page` does not get loaded automatically. It is loaded when viewing a cms page. Check `Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::_renderPage`. That's where it is used.

Comment: Yeah, I see it. renderPage is called by the index action. That's no magic, it's just logical. Even 'default' is added explicitely - until now I though this handle would automatically added to all requests. That's not the case as it seems. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get Handels used in the current page, try this

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandels();
```

Comment: My question was not which handles does a request takes into account. My question was about how does this get determined.